# Where is the "UserKey" stored used in "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey"?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Where Can I find the userkey where the `SSIS` packages uses for protection `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`.

1.Is it Editable?

2. if I create a new SSIS Project with my new profile, can I copy the "UserKey" from the new Project into my old Projects to allow EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey to work properly in my old Projects with my new Profile?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  That sounds like a "hacking into someone's SSIS package" kind of question.

Comment: Hey Brian It's not about hacking...I have created a package on my local machine just wanted to find the user key where it will get stored. Just for a knowledge purpose.

Comment: A quick Bing search found multiple articles on the topic of SSIS package security - here's an example:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2091/securing-your-ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/

Comment: TL;DR - I believe the answer is "no" to both of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The UserKey is likely using a guid/sid associated to your local/AD account. Windows has to have "some" way of uniquely identifying your account that isn't just the name. It then uses that unique value as the key to encrypt potentially sensitive data.

There is nothing you can do to edit the value. You can create a new user on your computer and it will get a new value generated but you can't influence the value.

Every project you create with that user id will encrypt/decrypt the sensitive data just fine. It's only when you transfer work between computers (in a non-active directory situation) that this becomes an issue.